# Magento: Order of categories doesn't reflect on the frontend

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm on Magento 1.4.1.1. The order of categories doesn't reflect on the frontend on a **certain categories**.

I order categories by draging-and-dropping categories right in category tree at the left-hand side of the "Manage Categories" page.

Please advise.

Comment: Stackoverflow is only for programing questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well i can advise to try to update to last version 1.7.0 if community and you can have some custom made categories template, if that's the case you will never see the changes in your ordering.

Comment: I'm planning for upgrading my Magento but it will take a long time as I'll build the template from scratch so is there any temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you re-index the catalog, on the frontend are you the default magento code for category listing?

Comment: Yes I have re-indexed the catalog and I'm using the default category listing

Comment: this might hep - http://www.novusweb.com/1622/e-commerce-technology/fixing-magento-category-order-problems#.UK5MZeSE3qM

Comment: Your suggested link solved my problem Thanks you very much :)